# How to deal with checked exceptions that cannot ever be thrown

Tags: java, exception-handling

Example:

```
foobar = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream(), "ISO-8859-1");
```

Since the encoding is hardcoded and correct, the constructor will never throw the UnsupportedEncodingException declared in the specification (unless the java implementation is broken, in which case I'm lost anyway). Anyway, Java forces me to deal with that exception anyway.

Currently, it looks like that

```
try {
    foobar = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream(), "ISO-8859-1");
}
catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e) { /* won't ever happen */ }
```

Any ideas how to make it better?

Comment: For a real challenge, write a unit test to make sure this catch actually works.

Comment: `throw new ImpossibleException("Reboot the universe. Things are messed up", e);

Comment: "Won't ever happen" will...

Comment: Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: it might after changing the program, but at least in its current state, no set of input data can trigger the exception.

Comment: In your specific example above, an exception is thrown because the method does not know whether it will be called with a supported or not supported encoding. A way around this would be if there was another constructor that assumed a standard charset was given, which wouldn't need to declare that an exception would be thrown.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

My habit is, just to be on the safe side, to put an `assert` into the catch block. Someone might change the contents of the `try` block later, and you do want to know if the code fails don't you?

Comment: Good idea; a simple `assert false;` doesn't add too much clutter and makes it clear that I assume the catch block will never be entered.

Comment: @ammoQ, or you can even add a message to make your intent absolutely clear: `assert false : "should never happen"`.

Comment: Even better, "Should never happen because Java requires the charset ISO-8859-1 to be supported."

Comment: `assert` implies assertions are enabled. I throw an `UnexpectedException` (which also has the benefit of letting me have a stack trace...).

Answer (score 35):

If I had been given a cent for every time I've seen an log/error, "This should never happen", I would have...  well, two cents.  But still...

Empty catch blocks makes my spider senses tingle and most good code analyzer tools complain.  I would avoid at all costs to leave them empty.  Sure, now you know the error can never happen, but a year from now someone does a global search-replace of "ISO-8859-1" and suddenly you may have an extremely hard to find bug.

The `assert false` suggestion is good, but since assertions [can be disabled](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html#enable-disable) at runtime, they are no guarantee. I'd use a `RuntimeException` instead. Those won't have to be caught by calling classes and if they ever occur you will have a stack trace to give full information.

Answer (score 28):

I've always done it like this:

```
try {
    foobar = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream(), "ISO-8859-1");
} catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    throw new AssertionError(e);
}
```

May be a bit verbose (Java is...), but at least you'll get an assertion error when the impossible happens.

If the Java implementation is broken, you'll want to get as good error message as possible, as quickly as possible, instead of just ignoring the impossible. And even if the Java implementation isn't broken, someone could have changed *your* code to `"UTF8"` (oops - should it have been `"UTF-8"`?).

This *should* have been a runtime exception in the first place. JDK is full of this sort of wrong choices.

Comment: The real bad decission (or omission if you want) is that there are no pre-defined Charset instances for those 6 charsets that Java requires. `foobar = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream(), Charset.ISO_8859_1);` - now wouldn't that be nicer and avoid any mistake once and forever?

Comment: The Guava library has tons of these things.  Makes life easier.

Comment: Java 1.7+ does have charset constants defined: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html. Use them like so: StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName()

Answer (score 4):

If you are the only developer who will ever get to see this code then I'd say its fine, but if you are not then I would treat it as a real possibility or at least change the "won't ever happen" comment to something more useful.

Answer (score 4):

The part of these exceptions that annoys me most is that it hurts my code coverage.

When I'm getting compulsive about coverage, I'll roll up the try / catch that "can never happen" (...or only if I'm using a mutant JVM that somehow forgot to include "US-ASCII") into a class and method that encapsulates that try / catch, and replace the checked exception in one of the ways mentioned here (usually throwing an unchecked exception with a snide message).

Then my code coverage takes a hit in the utility class, but not in all the references to that operation scattered around my code.

Sometimes I'll take the time to roll up like operations in a class that actually has coherent semantics. But since it's pretty obvious to my teammates what's going on, I usually just keep it as simple as I can & not worry so much about the best possible design.

However, as a comment mentioned, Guava & other libraries have ways to mitigate this pain -- but that's basically the same strategy. Move the annoyance off-stage so your main code doesn't take the hit in coverage.